# explain this shell command with redirection and pipe

Tags: shell, pipe, io-redirection

I can understand the statements like.

1. `bzip2 --version >/tmp/list_right 2>/tmp/list_error`
2. `bzip2 --version >/tmp/list 2>&1`

But I don't understand the statement:

```
bzip2 --version 2>&1 < /dev/null | head -n1
```

Comment: `bzip2 --version` outputs info to `stderr` but *pipe* (`|`) transfer `stdout` only. So in the case to be able format info (prints just 1st line) the `stderr` of `bzip2 --version` is redirected to `stdout`. Is there any reason to input `/dev/null` I have no idea.

Comment: this question is not constructive.

Answer (score 1):

`2>&1` duplicates standard output as standard error. `</dev/null` redirects standard input to the null character special device, eof is encountered immediately when reading. `|head -n1` pipes standard output to the command, thus the first line is printed, and lines after the first are discarded.